# Why isn't my progress shown for Documentation reviews?

Tags: support, documentation

When I do review on questions and answers, I can see my progress toward a badge. But for Documentation reviews, I have no progress shown.

Why is my progress toward a badge not shown for Documentation? Where can I find it?

Comment: Because documentation review right now doesn't have any badge other than peer review which you will gather at your first review.

Answer (score 16):

Although I already answered in comment that there's only peer review badge is awarded right now but here's some thought crunch,

Progress badge's for review required

250 review for silver badge

1000 review for Golden badge

In documentation review hardly 1 or 2 proposal are in queue at a time and in a day 10 to 12 proposal wait for review in which even if you know more than three language and framework you seldom going to review 2 to 3 review per day.

Documentation reviews are sacred then your Q&A reviews you can't just looks ok or no action needed on documentation review. if some proposal ruining the example or topic passed by the sock puppets reviewer or badge hunters it will ruin the reputation of documentation which is currently in scrutinizing by community.

Comment: I think SO may gather stat about how many and how much user is not right. Example based on triage review: 1requires editing VS 3 Looks OK -- one time too much; 1 should be closed VS 3 Looks OK -- second time, too much; 2requires editing VS 2Unsalvadgeable VS 3 Looks OK -- third time, not much. Summary: user did three wrong sugestions and two of them very wrong. After some count of such suggestions we should count this user as low quality reviewer. Maybe count his vote as 0.9 or so