# No silver badge on reviewing 250 Documentation items?

Tags: support, documentation, badges

I recently finished 250 reviews on Documentation.
I understood that I should get a silver badge. I haven't got one yet.

Comment: Badges are awarded on a schedule. Patience, grasshopper, patience.

Comment: Last time I checked, the Documentation review queue did not have the Custodian/Reviewer/Steward badges. Documentation is a special case.

Comment: [Related question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339768/why-isnt-my-progress-shown-for-documentation-reviews/339792#339792)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Documentation review queue is special. Currently you can't be rewarded with review badges (Custodian, Reviewer, and Steward) for reviewing it.

Just one important remark: please don't review to receive a badge. It's definitely the worst motivation. Even killing time is much better one.

Comment: @Pri please have a look at the edit

Comment: Offcourse Yes. That make scenes.